# Print a document using C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

Up to now i am using following code. Using btnUpload I can upload the document. Using btnPrint I can send the document to printer.when I upload notepad it prints well.But when I upload word document it give me Print document also. But it contains not letters.Some kind of symbols with few letterers.How can solve this?

```
String content = "";

private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int numberOfPages = 0;
    string fileName;
    // Show the dialog and get result.
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
    {
       fileName = ofd.FileName;

       var application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
       //read all text into content

       try
       {
          content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fileName);
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

       }

       var document = application.Documents.Open(@fileName);
       numberOfPages = document.ComputeStatistics(WdStatistic.wdStatisticPages, false);
       MessageBox.Show("Total Pages"+ numberOfPages);
    }
}

private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
    PrintDocument printDoc = new PrintDocument();
    printDoc.DocumentName = "fileName";
    printDlg.Document = printDoc;
    printDlg.AllowSelection = true;
    printDlg.AllowSomePages = true;
    //Call ShowDialog
    if (printDlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        printDoc.PrintPage += new PrintPageEventHandler(pd_PrintPage);
        printDoc.Print();
    }
}

private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
    ev.Graphics.DrawString(content, new System.Drawing.Font(new FontFamily("Times new Roman"), 12f), Brushes.Black,
                        ev.MarginBounds.Left, 0, new StringFormat());
}
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but my first guess would be that you can't print a word document (=binary file) like a simple text file... Your printer doesn't know how to handle a word file.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. if you want to print the word document, cant you just call document.Printout();?

Answer (score 1):

You just can't print a binary file as it were a plain text, in order to print Word Documents you have to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.

Comment: Check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.printout(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you refer Microsoft.Office.Interop;

```
   Word.Application _app = new  Word.Application();
   Word.Document doc = _app.Documents.Open(refer fileName, ...);
   doc.PrintOut(/* refer options */);
```